# Как убрать все стили псевдокласса с объекта с помощью js или css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Как убрать все стили псевдокласса с объекта с помощью js или css. Допустим, есть

```
`<div class="block"></div>` 


`.block {background-color: green; width: 90%;}
.block:hover {background-color: red; width: 100%;}`
```

Как отменть все эти стили псевдокласса для мобильных устройств, и оставить изначальные?
P.S.: Вот такой вариант не подходит:

```
`@media (max-width:600px) {
  .block:hover {
    background-color: green; width: 90%;
  }
}`
```

Нужно сделать это одним действием, так как стилей может быть очень много

Comment: никак, разве что заменой класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Псевдоклассы не являются элементами, поэтому нельзя получить доступ к ним из JS.
Наверное, единственный способ изменить стили псевдокласса - использовать перекрытие через динамически созданный элемент `<style>`.

Что касается того, как убрать все стили псевдокласса - это непросто, тут всего три варианта:

- либо прописать в перекрытом style свойство `all: unset;` псевдоклассу, [надеясь что у пользователя не IE/Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all)
  *(имхо, это лучший вариант из возможных, несмотря на отсутствие поддержки браузерами MS)*
- либо перекрыть все объявленные CSS-свойства псевдокласса их стандартными значениями
  *(для этого нужно знать заранее, какие свойства объявлены, т.к. средствами JS это не узнать)*
- либо заменить класс элемента новым, перенеся в этот новый класс все стили из исходного.

Простой пример:

```js
let styleEl = document.createElement('style');
document.body.appendChild(styleEl);

test = document.getElementById('test');
test.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16);
  styleEl.innerHTML = `#test:after { color: #${randomColor}; }`;
});

let reset = document.getElementById('reset');
reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  styleEl.innerHTML = `#test:after { all: unset; }`;
});
```

```css
#test {
  font: bold 16px sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

#test:after {
  content: ', consectetur adipiscing elit.';
  display: inline;
  color: #4a4;
}

#reset { margin-top: 20px; }
```

```html
<span id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
<br>
<button id="reset">Удалить стили псевдокласса (all: unset;)</button>
```